# How can I get realtime streaming updates to a Gremlin query?

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, gremlin-server, janusgraph

I fell in love with realtime streaming updates to a query when I was using Firebase, RethinkDB and similar.  Now that I am working with graph databases via Gremlin, I'm wondering how to get this behavior.

As a trivial example, if I specified a gremlin query like:

```
g.V().values('name')
```

I'd like to receive an update when a new vertex is added with a name property, or a name is changed on an existing vertex.

I am beginning to use Janusgraph, so the ideal solution would work there -- but this is such a killer feature that I could be swayed to [other Gremlin-friendly graph databases](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/#graph-systems).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an [EventStrategy](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.3/reference/#_eventstrategy) with any Tinkerpop compatible graph database. Once you create the event strategy, you add it to your traversal `g = graph.traversal().withStrategies(strategy)`. You'll need to implement the [MutationListener](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/step/util/event/MutationListener.html) interface to do whatever you'd like to on those events.

Comment: Very cool!  Thank you.  I didn't say clearly, but I am sending my gremlin queries over websockets (via the normal `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer`) -- do you know if code similar to that running in console in the [EventStrategy](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.3/reference/#_eventstrategy) example would also stream updates over websockets, or if more wiring is needed?

Comment: You'd likely need to write an implementation of the MutationListener, but the EventStrategy should work out of the box. Keep in mind the warning mentioned at the bottom of that section, and you should be in good shape.

Answer (score 1):

OrientDB has LiveQuery though I don't know that it integrates with Gremlin - https://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Live-Query.html - that's the closest thing I know of to this kind of feature in any TinkerPop-enabled graph database